# .Net Does the code within a class always run on the thread that created it?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading

In the example code below, will the timer elapsed event always run on the background thread, or on the main thread?

```vb
Public Class MainClass    
    Dim SomeSubClassInstance As SomeSubClass

    Public Sub New()
        'Create a thread which will then create an instance of the sub class
        Dim T As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf CreateSomeSubClass)
        T.IsBackground = True
        T.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateSomeSubClass()
        'This code runs on the background thread, and creates the instance of SomeSubClass
        SomeSubClassInstance = New SomeSubClass
    End Sub

    Public Class SomeSubClass
        Dim WithEvents tmrDoWork As Timers.Timer
        Public Sub New()
            tmrDoWork = New Timer
            tmrDoWork.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds
            tmrDoWork.Start()
        End Sub

        Private Sub tmrDoWork_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs) Handles tmrDoWork.Elapsed
            'Will this code be run on the background thread that was created in the MainClass constructor?
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

Answer (score 4):

It won't run on either. It will run on a random thread pool thread unless you specify a SynchronizingObject which will marshal the calls to another thread.

If the SynchronizingObject property is null, the Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread. If processing of the Elapsed event lasts longer than Interval, the event might be raised again on another ThreadPool thread. In this situation, the event handler should be reentrant.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If stop the timer in the elapsed event, and re-enable it once the processing is complete to prevent re-entrancy, and i don't require that the class remains on the same thread then this would be ok?

Comment: It will still run on a random thread but it will never run multiple ellapsed timers at once. If this is the behavior you want you should set [AutoReset | https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset(v=vs.110).aspx] to false. Wrap the body of the Ellapsed event handler in a try finally. In the finally block set Enabled = true.

Comment: "but it will never run multiple ellapsed timers at once"

What do you mean by that? Because if you have 3 different threads spawning 3 classes containing timers. What stops one timer elapsing while another timer is currently doing some processing in its own elapse event?

Comment: My comment is applicable per instance of the timer. If you have 3 timers with AutoReset = false, you can have 3 Elapsed events running on 3 different threadpool threads simultaneously. If you only want 1 to be able to run, only use one timer, or put a lock in the elapsed handler.To be clear the thread in your example does nothing except create the timer, then it terminates. All of the timers ellapsed events are running on a threadpool thread.